# Is there a way to compare CSVs in Python while ignoring row ordering?

Tags: python, windows, csv

I'm setting up an automatic job that needs to parse csv files from an ftp site, each file contains several 10 thousand lines. I want to pre-process the directory to eliminate duplicate files before parsing the remaining files. The problem is that duplicate files are being pushed to the ftp but with different row ordering (i.e. same data, different order). That results in "duplicate files" having different hashes and byte-by-byte comparisons. with minimal processing.

I want to keep file manipulation to the minimum so I tried sorting the CSVs using the csvsort module but this is giving me an index error: `IndexError: list index out of range`. Here is the relevant code:

```
from csvsort import csvsort
csvsort(input_filename=file_path,columns=[1,2])
```

I tried finding and eliminating empty rows but this didn't seem to be the problem and, like I said, I want to keep file manipulation to the minimum to retain file integrity. Moreover, I have no control over the creation of files or pushing of the files to the ftp

I can think of a number of ways to work around this issue but they would all involve opening the CSVs and reading the contents, manipulating it, etc. Is there anyway I can do a lightweight file comparison that ignores row ordering or will I have to go for heavier processing?

Comment: How many columns do the csv files have? May be it is less than 3, which is causing the IndexError. Try `columns=[0, 1]` if it has only two columns.

Comment: @Samik the files have between 10 and 20 columns. I also thought along those lines, so I tried columns=[0] but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that `pandas` has a built in hash function with an option to ignore the index. As the hash is calculated on each row, you need to run an additional sum function. In terms of code, it is about as lightweight as I could wish, in terms of runtime, it parses ~15 files in ~5 seconds (~30k rows, 17 columns in each file).

```
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas.util import hash_pandas_object
from collections import defaultdict

duplicate_check = defaultdict(list)
for f in files:
    duplicate_check[hash_pandas_object(read_csv(f),index=False).sum()].append(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify how much data you have. My take on this would differ depending on size. Are we talking 100's of lines ? Or multi-million lines ?

If you have "few" lines you can easily sort the lines. But if the data gets longer, you can use other strategies.

I have previously solved the problem of "weeding out lines from file A that appear in file B" using AWK, since AWK is able to do this with just 1 run through the long file (A), making the process extremely fast. However you may need to call an external program. Not sure if this is ideal for you.

If your lines are not completely identical - let's say you need to compare just one of several fields - AWK can do that as well. Just extract fields into variables.

If you choose to go this way, the script is something along:

```
FNR==NR{
a[$0]++;cnt[1]+=1;next
}

!a[$0]
```

Use with

```
c:\path\to\awk.exe  -f awkscript.awk   SMALL_LIST   FULL_LIST  > DIFF_LIST
```

DIFF_LIST is items from FULL that are NOT in SMALL.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, this isn't really ideal for me, especially as I'm using a windows machine. I'm also trying to go as lightweight as possible. I must add, though, that I would probably go along these lines if I was working with bigger and more files. I'm thinking that perhaps an option would be to read each file into a `pandas` df, sort it and then get the hash of the df. I was trying to avoid this but it may be my best option. Not sure what you think. (I have edited my question to clarify the issues you pointed out.)